# Designated initializer and passing arguments

Tags: objective-c, ios, designated-initializer

I have this hierarchy:

```
CreateAnObjectClass : NSObject

MySecondClass : MyBaseClass
    MyBaseClass : NSObject
```

in CreateAnObjectClass I want to create an instance of MySecondClass method and i want to pass a `@property (strong,nonatomic) NSDictionary* myTemplate` to myBaseClass.

For example:

```
CreateAnObjectClass *testObj = [[MySecondClass alloc] initWithTemplate:myTemplate];
```

And I know that calls both initializers from MyBaseClass and MySecondClass.

```
(id)initWithTemplate:(NSDictionary*)myTemplate
{
  self = [super init]

  return self;
}
```

My question is how I should designe initializers to myTamplate can be a property at MyBaseClass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
- (id)initWithTemplate:(NSDictionary*)aTemplate
{
  self = [super init]
  if (self){
    self.myTemplate=aTemplate;
  }
  return self;
}
```

**Edit 1:**

Remember the following, calling this:

```
  self = [super init];
```

On the `MySecondClass` **will call the init method** on the `MyBaseClass`

Comment: But this create a property in MySecondClass. I need it in MyBaseClass

Comment: `MyBaseClass` is the super class of `MySecondClass`, so just put the init method on the `MyBaseClass`.

Comment: As i said i already know that, but what i don't know if i have to pass myTemplate to initializer to MyBaseClass? I should have initWithTemplate: in MyBaseClass?

Comment: Yes why not? I don't see why you didn't did that before.